# pandas key error only when using merge only in a function

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frames "base_level" and "raw_inventory" with the following columns:

"base_level" columns -> "a" , "b", "c" , "inventory_id"...

"raw_inventory" columns -> "1", "2", "3", "inventoryparentid",.....

when I use merge join directly as shown below, everything works as expected.

level = pd.merge(base_level, raw_inventory, left_on='inventory_id', right_on='inventoryparentid', how='left')

print(level)

But when I use it in a function and try to call as shown below

```
def inv_level ( child_inv, parent_inv, lefton, righton, how ):
      level_inv = pd.merge(parent_inv, child_inv, left_on=lefton, right_on=righton, how=how)
      return level_inv


level = inv_level(base_level, raw_inv, 'inventory_id', 'inventoryparentid', 'left')
print(level)
```

It throws the following error

```
  File "C:\temp\env\3.8.6\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 652, in __init__
    ) = self._get_merge_keys()
  File "C:\temp\env\3.8.6\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 1005, in _get_merge_keys
    right_keys.append(right._get_label_or_level_values(rk))
  File "C:\temp\env\3.8.6\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1563, in _get_label_or_level_values
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'inventoryparentid'
```

I am not able to identify what could be the reason. Any inputs regarding this issue is appreciated.

**Edit:**

I tried in following sample code to show case what I am trying to do and easy for understanding. I get the same error.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


def inv_level ( child_inv, parent_inv, lefton, righton, how ):
    level_inv = pd.merge(parent_inv, child_inv, left_on=lefton, right_on=righton, how=how)
    return level_inv


def main(event, context):
    np.random.seed(0)
    # transactions
    left = pd.DataFrame({'transaction_id': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 
                        'user_id': ['Peter', 'John', 'John', 'Anna'],
                        'value': np.random.randn(4),
                    })
    # users
    right = pd.DataFrame({'new_id': ['Paul', 'Mary', 'John', 'Anna'],
                        'favorite_color': ['blue', 'blue', 'red', 
                                            np.NaN],
                        })

'''
    test = inv_level(left, right, 'user_id', 'new_id', 'left') #left.merge(right, on='user_id', how='left')
     The above throws an error
'''
    test = pd.merge(left, right, left_on='user_id', right_on='new_id', how='left') 

    print(test)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main("", "")
```

**Error:**

*File "C:\temp\env\3.8.6\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 1005, in _get_merge_keys
right_keys.append(right._get_label_or_level_values(rk))
File "C:\temp\env\3.8.6\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1563, in _get_label_or_level_values
raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'new_id'*

Here is the intended output:

```
  transaction_id user_id     value new_id favorite_color
0              A   Peter  1.764052    NaN            NaN
1              B    John  0.400157   John            red
2              C    John  0.978738   John            red
3              D    Anna  2.240893   Anna            NaN
```

Thanks,

Comment: Check 'inventoryparentid' column on your dataframes.

Comment: @L.Papadopoulos  Thank you for your response. I did check the column and it exists. I added small python script with the sample data and it has the same error. Probably it helps to understand the issue.

Comment: Can you please, put the desired output? Of the testing dataframes?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
test = inv_level(left, right, left['user_id'], right['new_id'], 'left')
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried it and it is not the intended output.   Here is what I am getting.                                                                                                                             key_0 new_id favorite_color transaction_id user_id     value
0  Peter   Paul           blue            NaN     NaN       NaN
1   John   Mary           blue              C    John  0.978738
2   John   John            red              C    John  0.978738
3   Anna   Anna            NaN              D    Anna  2.240893